# Selenium automation results in "401 Unauthorized" error

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to automate a login to Zoom with selenium using python.
 However, the automation results with "401 Unauthorized" error. Despite that, logging in manually works just fine.
The error occurs after filling my credentials and clicking the login button.
I have checked the credentials, URL and even tried clearing the cache and cookies just like google suggests, but nothing seems to work...

Here is how I create my driver:

```py
options = FirefoxOptions()
options.set_preference("dom.push.enabled", False)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install(), firefox_options=options)
driver.get("https://us05web.zoom.us/signin")
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: could you explain better when and where the error appears? You got it just running your python script at the very beginning or when the driver tries to surf to the page and log in?

Comment: Less information to reproduce/understand this scenario. add the complete stacktrace

Comment: Hi, sorry for the inconvenience. I edited the question and added more details.